# laravel BelongsToMany pagination

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have 2 model

1 -  category with parent and child

```
class Category extends Model
{


protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $fillable = ['slug','title','icon','parent_id'];
/**
 * Get the index name for the model.
 *
 * @return string
*/
public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id','id') ;
}
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id','id');
}
public function posts(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'category_post');
}
public function latestposts(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'category_post')->latest()->limit(3);
}


}
```

2 - post model with belongsToMany->Category

```
class Post extends Model 
{

protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $fillable = ['user_id','slug','title','excerpt','content','keyword','img','status'];

protected $table = 'posts';


public function cat_posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_post');

}


}
```

example data treeview:

```
1-category parent 

 |- 1-child category -> with 5 post

 |- 2-child category -> with 3 post
```

Now, when viewing the main section -> (category parent), I want to display all the posts in all of the children's category 
To be the result of the number of posts = 8

And by pagination 
How can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to make a query to get all `subcategory` from your main `category`

in this example, I suppose that the first category is a main category

```
$subsCat = Category::first()->childs->pluck('id');
```

after that you can fetch all products with these categories `id`

```
Post::whereIn('category_post', $subsCat)->paginate(8);
```

and in case if you don't need to paginate you can make it in a single line 
using `each` from laravel `collection` like this one

```
$cat->childs->each(function($child){ 
   $child->posts;
})
```

you can read more about [each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-each) and [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) from the docs

> The first example with `paginate` is more efficient because it will make only two queries